# How do I navigate back to the main window in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a MainWindow.xaml which opens up bugsSplat.xaml in a frame.

In MainWindow.xaml, I have a code that looks like

```
<Frame Grid.Row ="1"  x:Name="_mainFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
```

In the MainWindow.xaml.cs,

```
scorePlayer.Play();
RightHand.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
mainMenuButtons.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
(Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("_mainFrame") as Frame).Source = new Uri("BugsSplat.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

What it does is that it plays a sound, hides the rightHand cursor and main menu buttons from the MainWindow and load BugsSplat.xaml into _mainFrame

My question is, how do I "hide" all new contents loaded from bugSplat.xaml and "unhide" the RightHand and mainMenuButtons so It will look like when you just started the application.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should not edit the question and add the answer. Instead add your answer as a proper answer. You could even accept your own answer. Although in this case you should accept the answer of Mario Vernari if it helped you find your solution. Also do not edit the title to include a note about the answer being available.

Answer (score 0):

Is it working the below code for you?

```
(Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("_mainFrame") as Frame).Source = null;
```

Comment: I added this code in BugsSplat.xaml.cs and it just clears the mainFrame. What I also need is to get the stuff I hide (RightHand and mainMenuButtons) to be visible again...

I also know that hiding them in the first place isn't the proper solution, do you have any suggestions?